# excel vba range.resize error 1004 (resizing non-contiguous area)

Tags: vba, excel

I am using developing vba excel for simple task to delete multiple cells from the worksheet.

The code starts with selecting cells with zero as a value:(which works fine)

```
Sub SelectRange()

Dim my_range1 As Range

For Each cell In Range("B17:AR17")

    If cell.Value = 0 Then

        If my_range1 Is Nothing Then

            Set my_range1 = cell

        Else

            Set my_range1 = Union(my_range1, cell)

        End If

    End If

Next
```

Then I would like to offset the selection to first row and select more rows from the first row: (the problem code)

`my_range1.Offset(-16).Resize(16).Select`

this line of code gives me the **error 1004**

I tested the code with offset only: (works fine)

`my_range1.Offset(-16).select`

I further tested the code with resize only: (problem code, **error 1004**)

`my_range1.resize(16).select`

I further tried with set, but still it gives me **error 1004**

`Set my_range1 = my_range1.Resize(16).Select`

I tried debug.print my_range1.address gives the following cells $B$17:$H$17,$K$17:$L$17,$O$17,$R$17:$AR$17 
but debug.print my_range1.value gives **error 13** type mismatch

I tried with the code provided:
`Set my_range1 = Union(my_range1, cell.Offset(-16).Resize(16))`
it says **error 424** object required

What I want to do is to resize the selection to include more rows and then delete them, but it didn't work.
Please let me know if further information is needed. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: As an aside, your code will also be including empty cells in the my_range1 i think

Comment: Also, Union can give you non contiguous range of objects back which i think may be the source of your problem. Have you checked the value of my_range1 when it fails?

Comment: I tried debug.print my_range1.address gives the following cells $B$17:$H$17,$K$17:$L$17,$O$17,$R$17:$AR$17
but debug.print my_range1.value gives error 13 type mismatch
Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can't resize a non-contiguous range

Comment: Why do you want to `Select` these areas?

Comment: (And a workaround is to actually do the resizing as you put the areas into the `Union`, i.e. `Set my_range1 = Union(my_range1, cell.Offset(-16).Resize(16))`, but I would still be interested as to **why** you want to do this - there is probably a better way.)

Comment: I would like to delete those cells so I have to select them.
So the problem is non-contiguous range? any workaround to select those non-contiguous area?

Comment: You don't have to `Select` cells to delete them.  Are you actually trying to **delete** the cells (shift cells left?, shift cells up?), or delete the entire columns, or just clear the contents?

Comment: Yes, I would like to delete them and shift the cells to the left. 
I don't want to delete the entire column because there are other things below the selected area.

Comment: OK, the workaround I suggested a few comments ago is probably the best way.  I won't put it as an answer at the moment, because someone might come up with a real "answer" rather than just a "work-around".

Comment: I tried with your workaround but it says error 424 object required

Comment: everyone is trying to fix your code, but I think your approach is not good to solve your problem, what do you want to solve? Maybe offset and resize is not what you need. You can work with the address of the cells instead of trying to keep them in a range object. Collect the address of the cells you need them inside one range object using their address (use x,y coordinates so you can easily manipulate the address) and then do whatever you want to do with them

Comment: If `Set my_range1 = Union(my_range1, cell)` was working, then using `Set my_range1 = Union(my_range1, cell.Offset(-16).Resize(16))` instead shouldn't give an "object required" error.  I have just tested, and it works fine for me.  (You will also need to change `Set my_range1 = cell` to be `Set my_range1 = cell.Offset(-16).Resize(16)` as well or the first column will only have row 17 chosen but, even without that fix, it still shouldn't crash.)

Comment: Now I see your suggestion is to replace my existing code. I misunderstood it as a new code to be added at the bottom of my code. That's why I get error 424. With the replacement of code, it works fine! Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't `Resize` non-contiguous cells, so a simple workaround would be to resize the individual cells prior to creating the `Union`:

```
Sub SelectRange()
    Dim my_range1 As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("B17:AR17")
        If cell.Value = 0 Then
            If my_range1 Is Nothing Then
                Set my_range1 = cell.Offset(-16).Resize(16)    
            Else
                Set my_range1 = Union(my_range1, cell.Offset(-16).Resize(16))    
            End If
        End If
    Next
```